# Cannot create external switch on Hyper-V

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I am getting the following error when creating an external switch on Hyper-V:

[image: Hyper-V Error]

I am running `Windows 8.1 x64`.

My switch settings are as follows:

[image: External Switch Settings]

Event viewer gives me the following errors in `Applications and Services Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Hyper-V-VMMS` in the order of logging:

1) Timed out trying to acquire network configuration lock, current owner = 'Binding Engine Task Queue Handler'.

2) Switch delete failed, switch = 'C8486DBE-CFB6-4355-99E3-19CD37C6D606': Operation times out (0x80041069).

3) Failed while removing virtual Ethernet switch.

Comment: did you solve this problem? I'm getting the same error and I have the same wireless network card :(

Comment: @andrecarlucci Sorry, no solution yet. I stopped using `Hyper-V` in the end. It would be nice to learn why this happened though...

Answer (score 1):

If you can't cretae external switch on Hyper-V.

> First you need to create a new internal virtual switch.In order to do that, kindly follow the below steps.
>
> Open the Hyper-V Manager and select your server.
>
> In your Hyper-V Manager window, Top of the screen to the left side the second option is "ACTION". Click on ACTION.
>
> In the ACTION tab now select "NEW VIRTUAL NETWORK" and "INTERNAL" and click on "OK".
>
> In machine, Go to

CONTROL PANEL ==>  NETWORK AND SHARING CENTER ==> MANAGE NETWORK CONNECTIONS.

> Now locate the active Wireless network adapter and do RIGHT click on the "PROPERTIES"
>
> Click on "SHARING" tab and check the box which has the option "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection".
>
> Now go to Hyper-V manager and do "RIGHT" on the respective server and click on

SETTINGS ==> NETWORK ADAPTER ==> in virtual switch drop down choose the EXTERNAL VLAN (NAME YOU GIVEN) and enable the Virtual LAN identification.

Comment: What I got in the Network Adapter -> Virtual switch for the virtual machine is only the virtual switch I created (the internal one). I don't have the EXTERNAL VLAN switch you mentioned. Is it automatically created somehow?

Answer (score 0):

1)Did you try launching Hyper-V Manager with Administrative rigths? .

2) Try closing the properties Windows because your network adapter might be running another instance which is making some conflicts

Comment: None of this helped in my case. I was surprised that I was able to create *Internal Virtual Switch* worked after I clicked *Stop Service* in **Actions** followed by *Start Service*

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have a switch bound to that NIC? If you don't see it in the GUI use the nvspbind.exe tool at an elevated prompt as in this Microsoft Article.

[Creating V-switches within the hyper-V environment fails](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2486812/en-us)

It will show you what virtual switches are attached to the NIC and allow you to unbind them.

Comment: nvspbind download located [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Hyper-V-Network-VSP-Bind-cf937850)

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a problem with hyper-visors and bridging a wireless NIC, i have tried and never succeeded even on VMWare or VirtualBox. So no bridge on a wireless NIC on a Virtual Machine.

The solution is to create a loop-back interface on Windows and bridge that one with the VM, and then share the wireless connection with other interfaces on PC.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from the related question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/762226/cannot-create-virtual-switch-hyper-v-0x80070002/1582035).
I was able to reoslve my *only similar but exact same error code* problem by going on the vendor's website to get my specific and latest driver executable. Installed it, rebooted and gone! The probleme was gone.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is what make it work for me.

Run command prompt as Admin and run **"netcfg -d"**

```
c:\> netcfg -d
```

then reboot, and the virtual is fine, and the above dialog working and let me make new virtual network