# Cannot create virtual switch Hyper-V (0x80070002)

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, virtualization, hyper-v

I get following error while creating any type(external, internal and private) of virtual switch on Hyper-V using Hyper-V manager.

> Failed to create virtual ethernet switch.
>
> The system cannot find the file specified. (0x80070002)

Here is a to screenshot of error:

[image]

OS: Windows 8.1 (x64) + Update 1

Getting the same error when trying to create from Powershell.

Comment: Here check this similar discussion http://superuser.com/questions/636048/cannot-create-external-switch-on-hyper-v which may help you.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to Settings -> [Network & Internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNZoz.png)
2. Select [Change adapter options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6WOF.png)
3. Right click on NIC Adapter -> [Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OV2J.png)
4. Check if [the Hyper-V Extensible Virtual Switch is installed in your NIC's Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75wsb.png)

   - If it is installed, [uninstall it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ6eD.png)
5. Reinstall the Hyper-V Extensible Virtual Switch

   5.1 Select [Install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p79hX.png)

   5.2 Select [Protocol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BIph.png)

   5.3 Select Hyper-V Extensible Virtual Switch
6. Create the virtual switch on Hyper-V using the Hyper-V manager

Source: https://www.tenforums.com/virtualization/10699-hyper-v-error-when-creating-virtual-switch.html#post306179

Comment: Did not work for me. Server 2019.

Comment: I had my wifi adapter already sharing, had to disable it first

Answer (score 0):

All resolutions suggested failed!

This did work immediately and I have had no issues since. Here is how you do it:

Open the following registry key and give "All Applications" full control permissions

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WcmSvc`

That was it, no more issues after that.

Answer (score 0):

All I did was delete the NICs from device manager one at a time (was logged in remotely). After deleting, right click and click *Scan for hardware changes*.

Windows re-found the deleted NIC and installed it, then Hyper-V manager was able to create a V-Switch.

For the Intel NICs, I did need the latest driver from Lenovo's site. I did not have to uninstall and reinstall the Hyper-V role; maybe because I had already tried the remove role → reboot → `netcfg -d` (PowerShell) → reboot again. (I had to use LogMeIn scheduled restart as I was working remotely)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue for a while. I tried a lot of different "solutions" for me the only thing that actually worked is to run these two PowerShell commands. 
First

```
Get-NetAdapter
```

This will just list all the network adapters on your machine. We need the name column for the actual command we want to run.

```
New-VMSwitch -name ExternalSwitch  -NetAdapterName Ethernet -AllowManagementOS $true
```

- `-name` is how the adapter appears in Hyper-V.
- `-NetAdapterName` is the name from the previous command.
- `-AllowManagementOS` is `$true` for the host and VM to both have internet. 
  This is a checkbox in the Hyper-V graphical interface.

I did try many things first to no avail. Resetting network settings, reimaging, `netsh` commands that I assumed were discontinued by now. Removing and re-adding the Windows features. I can't say this alone fixed my issue. However, the above is what seems to work for me. Trying the others all still result in the error message even now.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/get-started/create-a-virtual-switch-for-hyper-v-virtual-machines
This has a bit more info if anyone is interested.

Comment: Even with my edits, I find your answer technically confusing and unclear. Please clarify which words are literal and which are placeholders. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Instant fix on my 180 Eval Datacenter 2019. I added Hyper-V but couldn't select a network adapter. Did this, and it worked. If your NetAdapterName is "Ethernet 2" you can just add "quotes" around it in the given command. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create the external virtual switch on my server.

The problem was **the driver** used by the previous WS2016 OS was kept during my migration to 2019. I went on the vendors drivers download page to get the latest available network driver for my server (be very carefull selecting the proper driver here). I then rebooted because I could and the problem was gone !

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is what make it work for me.

Run command prompt as Admin and run **"netcfg -d"**

```
c:\> netcfg -d
```

then reboot, and its working

Comment: It's usually recommended here to also include what the command does, and preferably why it works, so people don't just randomly run commands they don't really know what they do, and potentially screw something on their system up. Just a helpful tip.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Disable Vmq before creating a switch:

```
C:\Users\Administrator> Get-NetAdapter
```

```
Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------             ---------
Ethernet                  Intel(R) Ethernet Connection X722 fo...       7 Up           3C-EC-EF-81-2F-37         1 Gbps
Ethernet 2                Intel(R) Ethernet Connection X722 ...#2       5 Up           3C-EC-EF-81-2F-36         1 Gbps
```

```
C:\Users\Administrator> Disable-NetAdapterVmq -Name Ethernet

C:\Users\Administrator> New-VMSwitch -InterfaceAlias 'Ethernet' -Name vSwitch1 -AllowManagementOS $true -EnableIOV $false
```

```
Name     SwitchType NetAdapterInterfaceDescription
----     ---------- ------------------------------
vSwitch1 External   Intel(R) Ethernet Connection X722 for 1GbE
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another fix that worked for me: after you enter the name of virtual switch, type of network (external,private...) apply and ok, a window may appear you say yes, and now is creating, now fast go to your physical network adapter, disable it and enable it back on, the virtual switch will be created without error. Best regards!