# How to remove a Hyper-V virtual Ethernet switch

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

A stale VM switch in Hyper-V is no longer used and when I try to delete it, it always fails with the following message:

```
PS C:\> Get-VMSwitch nat

Name SwitchType NetAdapterInterfaceDescription
---- ---------- ------------------------------
nat  Private


PS C:\> Get-VMSwitch nat | Remove-VMSwitch -Force
Remove-VMSwitch : Failed while removing virtual Ethernet switch.
Switch delete failed, switch = 'acf82f05-c07c-4b35-8588-921498456027':    General access denied error (0x80070005).
At line:1 char:20
+ Get-VMSwitch nat | Remove-VMSwitch -Force
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Remove-VMSwitch], VirtualizationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveVMSwitch
```

Attempting to delete within the GUI does not work, either:

[image: GUI]

Comment: access denied error = permission issue. do you use admin?

Comment: yes, I'm running as administrator. I noted that error is misleading. The underline network adapter is gone in network share center, I believe that is the error, but how can I remove this vmswitch.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A similar problem was resolved on Microsoft's TechNet forums:

> We have a virtual switch setup in the Virtual Switch Manager and the adapter has been deleted by mistake using the "Change Adapter Settings..." of the Network And Sharing Center. Now, obviously the switch is in a failed state and we just want to remove it from the list.

Ultimately, the OP performed an in-depth search within the registry and found the virtual switch configuration stored within the following key:

> HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\VMSMP\Parameters\SwitchList

After they deleted the corresponding value within that key and rebooted, the virtual switch was gone.

As always, I would recommend that you export your current settings to a `.reg` file to have an appropriate backup before attempting similar changes.

(Source: [Can't remove failed virtual switch from Hyper-V's Virtual Switch Manager](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e49df568-4f4c-47b7-b30c-952d1e26ca58/cant-remove-failed-virtual-switch-from-hypervs-virtual-switch-manager))

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me. Thx

Comment: I cannot find such value in registry :/

Comment: This worked for me, however I ALSO had to dig into the Network Connection in the registry to delete it.
This still left all the references to the docker svc in the registry:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\vmsmp\parameters\SwitchList\{yada yada}
and 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSEt001\Control\Network\{yada yada}

Answer (score 25):

I didn't want to install the Azure Powershell tools so I just followed the steps in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V5Gb342gSGg

Basically you go to Network Connections -> open properties for the virtual switch you want to delete -> click Configure -> go to the Driver tab -> Uninstall Device.

To prevent the Hyper-V service from creating a new one next time I restart my computer without disabling it altogether I changed the Startup Type of each Hyper-V service to be Manual.

Comment: This still left all the references to the docker svc in the registry:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\vmsmp\parameters\SwitchList\{yada yada}
and 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSEt001\Control\Network\{yada yada}

Comment: By far the best solution. Avoiding touching registry should be a best practice.

Answer (score 16):

Even though I'm not using Docker, I wanted to figure out a solution without using `regedit`, so after attempting [the answer from RobV8R](https://superuser.com/a/1213816/24543), I found instructions on [this question on MS Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/0aadbb19-f3cb-4539-a377-b1a67dbcdcdc/hyperv-1709-default-switch-is-it-manageable?forum=win10itprovirt).

```
Get-HNSNetwork | Remove-HNSNetwork
```

Or, for a more filtered optoin, this is what I needed.

```
Get-HNSNetwork | ? Name -Like "Default Switch" | Remove-HNSNetwork
```

Also, I'm going to assume that you'll want to follow @mxgg250's advice, and set all hyper-v services to manual start, otherwise it's going to recreate the switch on reboot.

Comment: "Get-HNSNetwork | ? Name -Like 'nat' | Remove-HNSNetwork" - Worked nicely to remove the 'nat' VMSwitch left behind after uninstalling Docker for Windows, thanks!

Comment: … which is also documented on Microsoft's cleanup Docker instructions https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon#step-3-cleanup-docker-data-and-system-components

Comment: I had no network adaptor named DockerNAT, yet that's the virtual switch I wanted rid of in Hyper-V Manager. This solution fixed it for me and now I can run Docker Desktop again.

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure if this is right but worked for me:
https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/unable-delete-network-adapter-windows-10/

---

## UPDATE

> Source: [Unable to Delete Network Adapter in Windows 10?](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/unable-delete-network-adapter-windows-10/)

### Method 1 – Use Device Manager

The first thing you can try to do is open Device Manager (click on start and type device manager), expand Network Adapters, and then right-click on the network adapter you want to remove.

[image]

Here, you will see an option called Uninstall device. This should hopefully not be greyed out. If it is, continue to the next method. When you select uninstall device, another window will appear asking to confirm the uninstall.

[image]

You’ll also see an option to delete the driver software for the device. If you want to completely remove the network adapter, I suggest selecting this option to remove the driver also. If all goes well, you should see that the adapter has been removed from both Device Manager and the list of network adapters in Control Panel.

If you don’t see the device listed here, you can try to click on **View** and then **Show hidden** devices.

### Method 2 – Delete Network Profile

We can also try to delete the network profile via the command line and then try Method 1 again. First, you have to open an elevated command prompt by clicking on Start, typing in CMD and then right-clicking on command prompt and choosing **Run as Administrator**.

Now type in the following command to see all wired (Ethernet) adapters:

```
netsh lan show profiles
```

If you need to remove a wireless adapter, type this command:

```
netsh wlan show profiles
```

If you get some error message about the **Wired** or **WLAN AutoConfig service** not running, then click on Start, type in services.msc, right-click on the appropriate service and choose **Start**.

[image]

Now when you run the command, you should see a list of profiles. In my case, I only have one profile on this computer.

[image]

Next, type in the following command, which will delete the desired interface.

```
netsh lan delete profile interface="InterfaceName"
```

Again, if it’s a wireless interface, use **wlan** instead of **lan**. The interface name is listed at the top of each heading (**Profile on interface name**) when you ran the show profiles command. Once the profile has been deleted, restart your computer and try Method 1 again.

### Method 3 – Remove Adapter Settings via Registry

> #### IMPORTANT
>
> If you need to edit the registry, make sure you [backup the registry first](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-backup-registry/).

In addition to deleting the network profile, you can also try to remove the adapter settings via the registry. After you remove the settings, you can go back to method 1 and try to remove the adapter. To remove the settings, open the registry editor (click on Start and type in regedit.msc), and navigate to the following key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE - SYSTEM - CurrentControlSet - Services - Tcpip - Parameters - Interfaces
```

You’ll see several items listed with a long series of random numbers. If you click on each one, you’ll see the IP address that is assigned to that network adapter.

[image]

You can confirm which network adapter corresponds to that registry key by opening a command prompt (Start and type cmd) and typing in **ipconfig**.

[image]

As you can see, Ethernet adapter is the one that has an IP address of 192.168.1.233. So you would delete the key under Interfaces that starts with **{73123f2a-ad10-4f4b-900e…}**. If you click on a different interface, one of them will have the IP 192.168.247.1, which corresponds to the VMWare Network Adapter on the computer. Again, this only deletes the settings for the adapter, not the adapter itself. Restart the computer and try Method 1 again.

For further information please referto the following link:

https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/unable-delete-network-adapter-windows-10/

Answer (score 7):

**BEGIN EDIT**

Newer versions of Windows 10 introduced a "Default Network" virtual switch.

If this method doesn't work for, Please see the response from @bradlis7 for another option.

**END EDIT**

**This was tested on Windows 10 1607.**

**Short Answer, if you're using Docker:**

```
PS> Stop-Service com.docker.service
PS> Remove-ContainerNetwork -Name nat
```

**Long Answer:**

If you run into this situation and have Containers enabled or Docker installed, you'll need to stop Docker before you can remove the VMSwitch.

```
PS> Get-VMSwitch

Name                                   SwitchType NetAdapterInterfaceDescription
----                                   ---------- ------------------------------
DockerNAT                              Internal
nat                                    Internal
Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch Private
Primary Virtual Switch                 External   Intel(R) Wireless
```

As you can see, I have a VMSwitch named `nat`.  I want it to go away.

```
PS> Remove-VMSwitch -Name nat

Confirm
Are you sure you want to remove the virtual switch "nat"?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
Remove-VMSwitch : Failed while removing virtual Ethernet switch.
Switch delete failed, switch = '<guid>': General access denied error (0x80070005).
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-VMSwitch -Name nat
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Remove-VMSwitch], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveVMSwitch
```

The answer turned out to be rather simple.  Because I had configured the `nat` VMSwitch with a NetNat, I removed the NetNat.  I'm unsure if this is a necessary step, but I did it anyway.

```
PS> Get-NetNat -Name '<name>' | Remove-NetNat
```

Then I stopped Docker.

```
PS> Stop-Service com.docker.service
```

And finally

```
PS> Remove-ContainerNetwork -Name nat

Confirm
Remove-ContainerNetwork will remove the container network "nat".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

To make sure it was gone:

```
PS> Get-VMSwitch

Name                                   SwitchType NetAdapterInterfaceDescription
----                                   ---------- ------------------------------
DockerNAT                              Internal
Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch Private
Primary Virtual Switch                 External   Intel(R) Wireless
```

Comment: FYI, this procedure may not work. It doesn't work for me. No docker service is running, still can not renive the dangling `nat`. So, it may be necessary to resort to the @Run5K answer

Answer (score 3):

Well, I spent a day trying to figure out what's wrong with it. I had slow internet after some moment - I event did not touch anything related to internet connections.

So, my solution is:
[image]

As you can see you just need to uncheck Hyper-V config in your standard internet connection by default. That's it - after that I got it working.

It may look that it is not an answer but it really can help people like me.

Comment: you saved me, thx for sharing this!

Answer (score 2):

Before trying the solutions above, make sure to check the 'details' pane for the error message. In my case, it read that the failure occurred due to other VMs still using the switch.

Turning the VMs **off** and trying again, did remove the switch.

[Details pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpGIh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way to fix the problem on Microsoft's TechNet forums:

> Try Deleting the [**Bridge Adapter**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVagS.png) from "**Control Panel** > **Network and Internet** > **Network Connections**"

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverhyperv/thread/e49df568-4f4c-47b7-b30c-952d1e26ca58/#8ecfa676-3184-4035-96de-10df079f706f

Comment: I do not have a Bridge Adapter.

Comment: @johnny Can you share a screenshot of your network adapters from the "Network Connections" window? Maybe you can solve it by uninstalling the Hyper-V Extensible Virtual Switch protocol following the instructions from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1273589/840977).

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the access denied error on two machines.

On one machine i had to run `Get-HNSNetwork | Remove-HNSNetwork` AND delete the networks reg keys in this location  `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\VMSMP\Parameters\SwitchList`

On the second machine only the reg key deletion was needed.  On the second machine i found that after deleting the regkey for the switch i only needed to restart the following service to make the UI update - reboot not needed in my case.

- Host Networking Service
- Hyper-V Management Service