# Unable to bind hyper-v virtual switch to ethernet adapter

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, network-protocols, bindings

I'm having trouble creating a virtual switch for a virtual machine I have in hyper-v.  I had a virtual ethernet switch set up and connected to the machine before, after deleting this at some point, I now cannot create one again.

Within hyper-v the error is:

[image]

After researching the problem, this appears to be related to the 'Hyper-V Virtual Extensible Switch'  item not being checked in the ethernet adapters properties.

[image]

Trying to enable this in the GUI isn't possible, as after checking the item then clicking on OK the message is "Your current selection will also disable the following features:
Hyper-V Extensible Virtual Switch", like here: https://www.tenforums.com/virtualization/31369-cant-enable-hyper-v-extensible-virtual-switch-networking.html

Within powershell when trying to enable this the error is

> PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> Set-VMSwitch Internet
>   -NetAdapterName "Ethernet"
>   Set-VMSwitch : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual switch with name "Internet". At line:1 char:1
>
> Set-VMSwitch Internet -NetAdapterName "Ethernet"                                                                      + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Set-VMSwitch], VirtualizationException                                   +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   ObjectNotFound,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.SetVMSwitch

Using the following command with a microsft uitilty called nvspbind:

> nvspbind.exe" /b "Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller"

the result is:

> applying changes... cleaning up...releasing write lock...success
>   finished (0)

But inspection afterwards using the properties GUI, powershell and nsvpbind reveals that the virtual switch is in not binded (all list as not binded).

Any ideas?

Specs: 
Windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: Tries: (1) Uninstall the Hyper-V feature in Windows, reboot, re-install, reboot, re-create the switch and try again. (2) Disable temporarily the anti-virus. (3) Try all the answers in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/762226/cannot-create-virtual-switch-hyper-v-0x80070002).

Comment: Yes I saw that other question too. All tried.

Comment: Anyone know why this might have been downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

If by a small chance you arrive here because you turned off Hyper-V Services on a windows OS for some reason, and then got this error when you tried to turn Hyper-V services back on, then the below should fix it:

Go to the Network Adapters and find the adapter for your physical network card. In properties, unselect the flag 'Hyper-V Extensible Virtual Switch', restart.

Comment: This solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

With `Get-NetAdapter` you can get a list of your physically network adapters.

Here the documentation of [Set-VMSwitch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/set-vmswitch).

Call this as admin in a Powershell Window:

`Set-VMSwitch -Name "My New vSwitch" -NetAdapterName "Ethernet" -SwitchType "External"`

**My New vSwitch** --> Name of new virtual Switch
**Ethernet** --> Name of Adapter (LAN, WLAN) from the output of Get-NetAdapter
**External** --> Switch Type, could be internal, external or private

Answer (score 0):

You have tried everything, including re-installing the Hyper-V feature in Windows,
but it didn't work out.

The explanation might be some over-active security application or a corruption
in Windows.

I suggest the following measures:

- Disable all security software, antivirus and firewall and try again
- Run chkdsk
- Run
  [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html) 
  and DISM
- If all fails then do
  [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: All tried, except repair install.